# how does intellij/maven determine what version maps to the value jdk.version in a pom.xml file?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

in one of the pom files, I have the following

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

which, I suspect is why that particular app has these following values on the settings page for the compiler
[image]

and resolves to language level 14 on the project structure page

[image]

Despite the fact that I keep setting it to 8, after a few builds, it sets itself back to 14 despite the fact that my default compiler is set to 8 and I do not even have the compiler version 14 on my list of compilers on intellij.

Which leads me to 2 questions:

1. What sytem variables are intellij or maven reading from that prompts them to continously set the Language level to 14?
2. how do I change that so it remains at 8? I cannot change the entry in the pom.xml file for business reasons.

Comment: From where does Maven read `${jdk.version}`? Is this a property in the POM? Or the `setings.xml`? Or is it specified on command line?

Comment: Can you `mvn clean compile` from command line successfully? It looks like `${jdk.version}` is not defined anywhere so IDE can not resolve it.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Regarding your question of "where does maven read `${jdk.version}` from", if you mean where in my code is the property used, yes, it is specified in the pom file exactly how I have listed above. If you mean how does maven know what version that resolves to, I have no idea and that is what I am trying to figure out with this SO post. I do not see it specified anywhere on the command-line arguments

Comment: @Andrey I can right now cause I corrected the language level to 8 a couple days ago and intellij has not reverted it to 14 again yet. will let you know if I can when intellij does the revert again.